# Gerund in a sentence

Tags: gerunds

Please, could you explain why we should put in the sentence below the gerund of the verb **give**:

> As an educational consultant, I lead workshops on digital media at schools around the country, **giving** me an unusual glimpse into the hidden world of middle and high school students.

What does GIVING refer to - to the pronoun  I or workshops? Is it a relative sentence or complex sentence (reduced adverbial)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Leading workshops-  this is an adverbial phrase.

Comment: _Giving_ can't have _I_ as its subject because its object is _me_; it would be _myself_ if the subject were _I_. This participial clause (not a gerund -- gerunds are only noun clauses and this is an adverb clause, not the subject or object of a verb) is a reduction of a relative clause: _workshops on ..., **which give** me an unusual ..._ becomes _workshops on ..., **giving** me an unusual ..._

Comment: what happens if we replace giving with which gives

Answer (score -1):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> *Giving* can't have *I* as its subject because its object is *me*; it would be *myself* if the subject were *I*. This participial clause (not a gerund -- gerunds are only noun clauses and this is an adverb clause, not the subject or object of a verb) is a reduction of a relative clause: *workshops on ..., **which give** me an unusual ...* becomes *workshops on ..., **giving** me an unusual ...*

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn’t try to express this thought in this way. Your question exposes the awkwardness in this sentence. You’re struggling with the structure, and you wrote it. Imagine the reader’s response. Break the message into two sentences. “I am an educational consultant who conducts workshops across the country. These events give me an unusual glimpse into the hidden world of middle and high school students.”